# C# how to change object attributes dynamically

Tags: c#, enums, msagl

am reading this tutorial
 http://chalaki.com/how-to-program-msagl-glee-to-create-hierarchical-graph-layouts/519/

using the code sample.

[image]

am trying to make the attributes dynamic (i want to be able to load the attributes from a database later)

i have tried

```
string dColor = "Red"; 
string dShape = "Diamond";

Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Node n2 = graph.FindNode(strNode2);
n2.Attr.Fillcolor = Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Color.dColor;
n2.Attr.Shape = Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Shape.dShape;
```

but its not working, how do i do this or even read about doing this dynamically?

**[ANSWER]**
Am not sure if this is the best way,but it works.

--For Colors i did

```
using mColor = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color;
using sColor = System.Drawing.Color;

sColor c = sColor.FromName("Red");
graph.FindNode("test1").Attr.FillColor = new mColor(c.A,c.R,c.G,c.B);
```

--For the shape i did

```
 graph.FindNode("test1").Attr.Shape = (Shape)
 (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape),"Diamond");
```

where "test1","diamond" and "Red" values come from the database.

Answer (score 1):

A `Color` is not a `string`.

```
Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Node n2 = graph.FindNode(strNode2);
var someColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
n2.Attr.Fillcolor = someColor;
```

If you will be storing the colors in the database, you can use one of the static methods on Color:

```
string dColor = "Red"; 
n2.Attr.Fillcolor = Color.FromName(dColor);
```

If you will not stick to the named colors, there is also `Color.FromArgb(int);`

**EDIT**

Looks like they are using a different Color class from the one in System.Drawing here. I found [an example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9728385-6d6e-40b6-a225-b2265600c18e/convert-windows-color-to-msagldrawingcolor?forum=automaticgraphlayout) on the MSDN forums:

```
string color = "Red";
var cvtColor = new ColorConverter();
var sysColor = cvtColor.ConvertFromString(color);
n2.Attr.Fillcolor = new Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color(sysColor.R, sysColor.B, sysColor.G);
```

There is some [example code on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout):

```
n2.Attr.Fillcolor = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
```

Comment: i get an Error : CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color'

Comment: I hope you have an IDE where you can easily discover how this `Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color` works. If not, you can use ILSpy or dotPeek. I've updated my answer.